# C++ | void *data[1000]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is it appropriate way to keeps the pointers in statically allocated array this way in **C++**?

```
void *data[1000];
```

Is the size of `void*` various on 32 and 64 bit machines?

Comment: Appropriate for **what**? What do you plan to do with your bundle of void pointers? (Don't worry about the size of a void pointer.)

Comment: I wonder if the `data[]` array can store anything.

Comment: @Stan: *Anything*? You mean like `fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), myfile);`?

Comment: @Kerreck SB: =,= I know through operating the address you can do everything... I just meant I didn't know what kind of data were proper to store in `data[]`.

Comment: I may not be against `void*` but against 1000 as constant. Why not allocate them dynamically or store them in a `vector` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost certainly absolutely not appropriate. Void pointers are pretty damn bad to begin with, and mix them with mutable static data, and you have something quite awful. A primitive unwrapped array of a magic number size on top of that, and I'm very glad that I don't have that in my code. Of course, if you have to, then you have to, but in the incredible majority of new code, you won't need anything like this.

Yes, the size of void* varies.

Comment: ok, thanks. I wanted to be sure the 'void *data[1000];' is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

A far better choice than `void*` is to make every object derive from a base class and use `base*` instead.

A far better choice than a fixed size array is to use `std::vector<base*>` or a Boost pointer container.

Yes, the size of a pointer will be different between 32 and 64 bit systems - that's the whole point.

Comment: The *best* choice would be `boost::any`.

Comment: @DeadMG, that may be true, I've never had the chance to use `boost::any`. Base classes are far more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, size of `void*` will vary depending on system bitness.

It's impossible to say whether using a fixed size array and storing `void*` pointers in it is appropriate without more details - it's usually not a good choice, but sometimes you really have no other options.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Google finds about 250K matches so far.

Comment: That is appalling. "Bitness" should mean "whether or not something has bits". "The bitness of oranges scares me." If anything, the measure of something should be "-tude", like "bititude". "Your mom's CPU has a bititude of 16."